# How to replace a line in a file containing a $ sign with a value input from user using sed

Tags: unix, sed, csh

I have a file with a value for a variable being used which I want to substitute with a value input from the user. I tried the below

```
sed -i "s/^\$var.*/\$var = \"$uval\" ;/g" file
```

where uval is the input from the user 
example line in file is $var = "value" ; 
example value entered by user is unix and the required line in file is
$var = "unix" ; 
Currently I am getting Unmatched " . Can anyone point as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also provide the contents of `file` and expected output?

Comment: File sample contents:
$abc = "val" ;
$var = "value" ;
If user input is test then required output in file is 
$abc = "val" ;
$var = "test" ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(\$var = ")[^"]*/\1'"$uval"'/' input_file
$abc = "val" ; $var = "test" ;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. Why does this work only when we use the previous match \1?

Comment: @John `\1` is a back reference that returns the contents contained within the capturing parenthesis. If `\1` is  not used, only the variable will be returned excluding everything else within the find pattern space